# Default Date on Slicer & custom selection

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a date slicer which should show last 12 days as selected when report opens. Further, user should have flexibility to select any other date range.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmLuF.png)

Comment: What is your slicer type? add a screenshot with your question.

Comment: added it  filter that is present in Power bi

Answer (score 0):

Can you try **Relative Date** option for the date slicer as shown below image-

[image]

In this case, you can select **last 12 Days** in the slicer while publish. User can then switch to any other date range as per necessity. But while initial loading, report will always show last 12 days in the selection.

Comment: Thank you but users want only Date range they don't want to switch the types

Comment: @sureshramesh Not referring to switch the type. You can select any date range using the drop downs.

Comment: I didn't get you can you please provide more screenshots

Comment: Just change the slicer type to "relative date" and play with the slicer. You will understand everything.